# Show that $U_{14}\cong U_{18}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Because $|U_{14}|=|U_{18}|$ and both of them is cyclic and commutative, so i just need define a function $f : U_{14}\to U_{14}$ that f is homomorphism and bijective.
$f(1)=1, f(3)=5, f(5)=7, f(9)=11, f(11)=13, f(13)=17$
Is that function homomorphism and bijective? If not, what is the function?

Comment: Any two cyclic groups of the same finite order are isomorphic, so one doesn't need to exhibit an explicit isomorphism.

Comment: Remember that a homomorphism defined on a cyclic group is completely determined by its image on any generator. So, you can simply define the map by sending a generator towards a generator.

Comment: $f(3)=5$ implies $f(9)=5^2=7$ and $f(13)=5\cdot7=17$ and $f(11)=5\cdot17=13$, and $f(5)=5\cdot13=11$.

Comment: sending 3 to 5. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since
\begin{align}
\varphi(14)
&=14\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{7}\right)=6 \\[6px]
\varphi(18)
&=18\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{3}\right)=6
\end{align}
we know the two groups *can* be isomorphic.

If we consider $3\in U_{14}$ and its powers, we get
$$
1=3^0,\quad
3=3^1,\quad
9=3^2,\quad
13=-1=3^3
$$
so the order of $3$ is six.

Similarly, if we consider $5$ in $U_{18}$, we get
$$
1=5^0,\quad
5=5^1,\quad
7=5^2,\quad
17=-1=5^3
$$
so the order of $5$ is six.

Since the two groups are cyclic of the same order, they're isomorphic. You find all isomorphisms by sending one generator of $U_{14}$ (for instance $3$) to *any* generator of $U_{18}$; the number is $\varphi(6)=2$, so the generators are $5$ and $5^{-1}=11$. The isomorphisms are
$$
f(1)=1, f(3)=5, f(9)=7, f(13)=17, f(11)=13, f(5)=11
$$
and
$$
g(1)=1, g(3)=11, g(9)=13, g(13)=17, g(11)=7, g(5)=5
$$
where $3^k$ is sent to $5^k$ or to $11^k$ respectively.

Comment: this is very useful answer. thank you so much! May i ask another question? (a). i define $f : S_{3} \rightarrow S_{5}$ with $f = (45)^{0}$ for even permutation and $f = (45)^{1}$ for odd permutation. Is that homomorphism? (b). i define $g : D_{4} \rightarrow S_{5}$ with $g=(45)^{0}$ for $\rho_{0},\rho,\rho^{2},\rho^{3}$ and $g=(45)^{1}$ for $\mu_{1},\mu_{2} ,\mu_{3},\mu_{4}$. Is that also homomorphism? Thx!

Comment: @RezaHabibi In the first case you're actually defining a homomorphism $S_3/A_3\to S_5$ (where $A_3$ is the subgroup consisting of even permutations); then you compose with the canonical projection. Similarly, in the second case you are apparently defining a homomorphism $D_4/H\to S_5$, by taking into account that $H=\{\rho^0,\rho^1,\rho^2,\rho^3\}$ is a subgroup; since $H$ has index $2$ it is normal, so your definition is good.